# Strange behaviour of TypeScript String.split() function

Tags: angularjs, string, typescript, split

I have TypeScript model like this:

```
export class Product {
    id:number;
    name:string;
    brand:Brand;
    price:number;
    shippingPrice:number;
    description:string;
    photoName:string;
    productType:ProductType;
    purchaseCounter:number;
    rating:number;
    volume:string;
    ingredients:string;
}
```

and json file which populate this model:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "xxx",
  "description": "xxx",
  "price": 12.34,
  "purchaseCounter": 12,
  "photoName": "xx",
  "shippingPrice": 12.99,
  "volume": "xxx",
  "rating": 4.7,
  "ingredients": "A,B,C",
  "brand": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "xx"
  },
  "productType": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "xxx"
  }
}
```

Now in my TypeScript component I have function like this :

```
public getIngredients():String [] {
        return this.product.ingredients.split(",");
    }
```

Everytime when I am invoking this function I have error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

but when i change body of function to sth like this:

```
public getIngredients():String [] {
    if (this.product.ingredients == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return this.product.ingredients.split(",");
}
```

then eveyrthing is ok and split function work properly. Have You got any idea why checking if ingredients is not null fix it? I have to admin that I just start my adventure with js and ts. Thanks

UPDATE
I instantiating this Product variable here:

```
export class ProductOverviewComponent implements OnInit {
    private product:Product;
    private errorMessage:string;

    constructor(private productService:ProductService) {
        this.product = new Product();
    }

    ngOnInit():void {
        this.productService.getProduct()
            .subscribe(
                product => this.product = product,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

For now I hit to the json file but in future I will hit to server. Another think is that I pass product to another comopnent using @Input().

And this is how i call getIngredients function

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="property-text">
            <!--<h3 class="h3style">Ingredients</h3>-->
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let ingredient of getIngredients()">
                    {{ ingredient }}
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How are you instantiating this `Product` class with data? How are you calling `getIngredients`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TypeError` that you get is a JavaScript error raised at runtime and has nothing to do with TypeScript. It happens because `this.product.ingredients` is undefined. Your "fix" works because `undefined == null` is `true` in JavaScript which results in an early return inside `getIngredients()`. If you used the `===` operator to compare against `null` your fix would no longer work.

However, the question is then why `this.product.ingredients` is undefined? It may be because the TypeScript `this` context is lost inside `getIngredients()`. From the code you have provided it is impossible to determine if that is the case but there is a nice write-up about the problem in the ['this' in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript) article on Github which might help you solve your problem. A simple first check could be to add `console.log(this)` inside `getIngredients()` to see what `this` really is.